# Salesforce Design System

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a basic question with Grid Sizing params of Lightning Design System. The document recommends specifying default sizing parameter along with breakpoint parameter as per devices sizes. Say I need to display two columns, each of 100% in small devices; and of 50% in medium devices. I tried the following code

```
     <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
         <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-small-size--1-of-1 " style="border:1px solid black">Box1</div>
         <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-small-size--1-of-1 " style="border:1px solid black">Box1</div>
     </div>
```

but this does not work. I thought for all devices of size greater than 480px would follow standard parameter (1-of-2) size,  but results show that it is following "slds-small-size--1-of-1" .

To render columns of width 50% in medium devices, I have to specifically add the following:

> ```
>      <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
>          <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-small-size--1-of-1 **slds-medium-size--1-of-2**" style="border:1px solid black">Box1</div>
>          <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-small-size--1-of-1 **slds-medium-size--1-of-2**" style="border:1px solid black">Box1</div>
>      </div>
> ```

I agree that medium sizing devices have a width greater than 480 px, but then shouldn't the default sizing apply to them. Else, when the default sizing would we useful. In twitter bootstrap, we have fixed 12 columns width and no default sizes. Here, the concept seems to be different, Please help me clarify  this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is because SLDS is mobile first.

In your first example.

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
         <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-small-size--1-of-1 " style="border:1px solid black">Box1</div>
         <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-small-size--1-of-1 " style="border:1px solid black">Box1</div>
</div>
```

What you are telling SLDS is:

- **slds-size--1-of-2**: Set the default size to 50% for all screens. (This is not responsive)
- **slds-small-size--1-of-1**: For any screen which is 480px and above, the div width should be 100%

Now, If your page is open on any screen with greater than 480px width, it will show each div with 100% width.

Id you open your page on any device which has screen size less than 480px, the width will be set to 50%. You can check this here : [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyxeaN)

This happen because your break-point is set to 480px.

---

In your second code what you are saying additionally along with above two points is.

- **slds-medium-size--1-of-1**: For any screen which is 768px and above, the div width should be 50%

So the matrix would be something like that.

```
<480 px     ---50%
480 - 768   ---100%
>768        ---50%
```

---

Now where is this `slds-size--1-of-2` useful. It will be useful if your code looks something like.

```
 <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
         <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-large-size--1-of-1" style="border:1px solid black">Box1</div>
         <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-large-size--1-of-1" style="border:1px solid black">Box12</div>
     </div>
```

In this case the widths will be 50% for <1024px and 100% for >=1024px.

More reading here: [SLDS Sizing](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/sizing/)